# + selector doesn't work when second class is more specific

Tags: css

I don't understand why this selector works:

```
.toggle-input + .toggle-trigger
```

but:

```
.toggle-input + .ios-toggle  .toggle-trigger
```

doesnt.

Does second selector of + is relative to first class?

```
<div class="ToggleWidgets ios-toggle">
    <div class='toggle-switch'>
      <input class='toggle-input' name='toggle' type='checkbox'/>
      <label class='toggle-trigger'></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.toggle-input + .ios-toggle  .toggle-trigger
```

This selector works if the html code is:

```
<div class="toggle-input"></div>
<div class="ios-toggle">
  <div class="toggle-trigger"></div>
</div>
```